# Android - Dashboard layout with a statelist background drawable only for the icon

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a dashboard layout. It is different from the [google i/o's dashboard](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/widget/DashboardLayout.java) in the sense that the background of the image icon and the text below the icon is different.

In other words, the icon(image only) has a `StateListDrawable` for its background while the text has a transparent background. One way of doing this is to put this combination of the image and text in a LinearLayout and use it in the dashboard layout for each of the item which seems not-so-simple. Is this the only way I could do it? or is there a better and simple solution?

**Update** : You can take the project setup from [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31698866/DashBoardTest.zip) and experiment.

- The layout file `dashboard2.xml` is using the google's `DashboardLayout` class. In the main activity I'm just setting the contents of the view to be `dashboard2`
- In that project you will find a statelist drawable in the `drawable` folder by the name `dashboard_icon_bg_selector.xml`. I want the background of all the dashboard icons to be this statelist drawable.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: could you please post a picture of how you want it to look like? And maybe of how it looks like now?

Comment: Please check the update. I have posted a link to the project setup. Download it and you can try it by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution I can think of is to use a `LayerDrawable` as your TextView's topDrawable. I'll outline the idea, enumerate some details and attach a link to the modified example project below.

Code for a Button (in the layout file):

```
<Button android:id="@+id/home_btn_schedule"
    style="@style/DPDashBoardButton"
    android:text="button 1"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/dashboard_icon_bg_selector" />
```

Two LayerDrawables, one for the 'pressed/focussed/selected' state and one for every other state (rest):

**dashboard_icon_layer_background_selected.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dashboard_icon_background_selected" />
    <item android:bottom="14dip">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/btn_star_big_on_pressed"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**dashboard_icon_layer_background_rest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dashboard_icon_background_rest" />
    <item android:bottom="14dip">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/btn_star_big_on_rest"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Some particularities for this specific example:

- The reason why the star images are referenced as a bitmap is to prevent Android from scaling them to the container's full width and height. The bottom distance is added to actually center the star with respect to the background image (textSize=12, plus 2 for padding), which, to be honest, is quite ugly to hardcode like this. Without this offset, the centered gravity will put the star image inside the center of the whole container, so including the space the text adds.
- As such, replacing the item with the bitmap by `<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_on_rest" />`, will result in the star image being scaled up. Just try it once to understand the effect.
- This phenomenon is quite unfortunate, since we could potentially reference another xml drawable with above, taking advantage of all it's already defined states! That's why I actually had to copy over two of the star images from the Android repository: you *cannot* reference an xml drawable as a bitmap source and the actual images cannot be publicly referenced either. Try replacing the bitmap definition with `<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star" />` to see the image getting scaled up, but keep the predefined states intact.
- You could potentially workaround the scaling issue by creating 9patches out of the star images, making a StateListDrawable for the different states and reference the resulting xml drawable in a layer item. Although Android will still stretch the whole image to the container's full size, the 9patches can make sure only transparent pixels are getting scaled.
- // Edit: I realised there's another limitation to this approach, as tapping the text will not make the state of the icon change. This might be what you're after, but personally I'd say that from a user perspective it would make sense to have the whole thing respond to touch events...

Hope this makes sense! Just to show you the result: left is all in rest state, right is topleft button being pressed.

**[Zipped project here.](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0BzGgLCwBqmpkYTM4ZjZlNzQtYjhhYi00MWMxLWE5NDUtYTY2ZGMwMjYzYjFl&hl=en_US)**

[image: Modified example project]

Comment: I am not able to access the project. Can you please check it once?

Comment: your answer seem to solve my problem. I have one day more to award the bounty. I shall give it to you soon after looking into the project.

Comment: I double checked but didn't have problems downloading the modified project. Anyways, I also uploaded the zip file to Google Docs and updated the link in my answer. Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use just a `TextView` and set its background to be the `StateListDrawable`? If you need some space for the "icon" above, you could set the Gravity of the `TextView` to Bottom and set a fixed height to it.

**Edit:**
Better yet, you can use the `drawableTop` property:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:text="Example"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/statelist"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"/>
```

**Edit 2:** Following the Google example, you can set a style for the Button/TextView. It changed the background color because that is the system's default behavior. Try the following:

**main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<org.demo.DashboardLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/DashboardTextView"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/state_list_drawable"
        android:text="Item1" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/DashboardTextView"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/state_list_drawable"
        android:text="Item2" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/DashboardTextView"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/state_list_drawable"
        android:text="Item3" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/DashboardTextView"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/state_list_drawable"
        android:text="Item4" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/DashboardTextView"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/state_list_drawable"
        android:text="Item5" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/DashboardTextView"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/state_list_drawable"
        android:text="Item6" />

</org.demo.DashboardLayout>
```

And add this to your `values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="DashboardTextView">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item> <!-- White, you can change your text color here -->
</style>
```

Comment: I have added more information. Please take a look at that. That might help you.

Comment: I've added the Edit 2 above, see if that helps!

Comment: I haven't tried doing it this way. I will incorporate and let you know the observations soon. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted a link to the project setup. You can experiment on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this would be easily solved with the use of 9patch images as the resources for your different states, and the state list as the background drawable or the TextView, with drawableTop set to the icon... unless you want the icon change as well as the background?